# I do not understand TypedValue

Tags: android

to:

> (metrics.density) Density: 1.0 (metrics.densityDpi) Density Dpi: 160

Difference between:

```
float mm_1 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

And

```
float mm_2 = 1 * metrics.densityDpi * (metrics.density/25.4f);
```

Why is there this difference?

```
mm_1 = 1.33333333
mm_2 = 6.2992125
```

Comment: Find out how much a millimeter in dpi.

Answer (score 0):

`TypedValue.applyDimension()` doesn't convert from units to inches(which I assume you're trying to do, based on `25.4`).

It simply converts the value to what will be used by the system, depending on the current density. I'm assume you're using an `hdpi` screen to do this, since the density factor for `hdpi` is `4/3`. Try it with a `mdpi`, and it will probably end up 1.0, since it doesn't need converting.

Comment: Find out how much a millimeter in dpi.
I use a Samsung Ace.

Comment: DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);